# PHP/HTML Radio Button Checked on Default issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button, checked

Creating a radio button set based off of PHP/MySQL

Having an issue with a button being checked on default:
What it looks like:

[image]

The code:

```
$first = TRUE;
if (mysql_num_rows($result))
{
   for ($j = 0; $j < mysql_num_rows($result); $j++)
   {
     $currentCat = mysql_result($result, $j, 'category');
     if ($first == TRUE)
     {
       $first = FALSE;
       echo "<input type='radio' name='createCat' value='$currentCat' checked='checked' />$currentCat checked";
     }
     else
     {
       echo "<input type='radio' name='createCat' value='$currentCat' />$currentCat ";
       echo "non";
     }
   }
   echo <<<_END
   <br /><input type='submit' value='Create' /> $error
   </form>
_END;
}
```

Notice how the first box isnt checked
The output in HTML:

```
<input type='radio' name='createCat' value='opt1' checked='checked' />opt1  checked<input type='radio' name='createCat' value='opt2' />opt2 non<input type='radio' name='createCat' value='Accounts' />Accounts non             <br /><input type='submit' value='Create' />
```

Comment: I don't see where you set `$first` initially

Comment: Wasnt included. But as you can see from the echo "checked" is beside the first category. So first is obviously set to true.

Comment: That is a bit strange .. what is the resulting HTML?

Comment: See the picture. The 'checked' beside opt1 shows that the echo statement is made, and the first choice chosen properly. But for whatever reason checked='checked' doesnt work. The alternative 'checked' doesn't work either.

Comment: Works fine for me...any Javascript involved? Try not just refreshing the page, but clicking the URL in the address bar and pressing enter, which will make sure the form is in its initial state.

Comment: @user2058050 no I mean the HTML code

Comment: No JS or CSS involved. Also works almost exactly as shown on another page. Weird. Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean the resulting html code? It outputs as ill add above.

Comment: Have you tried it in a different browser? Something weird is going on here...if your PHP code is exactly what you've posted here, then it should work. The only reason I can think of other than the browser or a browser plugin misbehaving (or simply needing to reset the form as I mentioned above) is a typo.

Comment: Okay so next question is. Since I've been figthing this for hours. Why does it work in IE but not in chrome?

Comment: If you answer it Matt I'll give you cred.

Comment: Does it work if you change `checked='checked'` to just `checked`?

Comment: [Here's a live demo of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/wxSFq/). Works for me on Chrome & IE10. Perhaps you have other `radio` buttons with the same `name` on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Change your first option to look like this and it should default to checked:

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='createCat' value='$currentCat' checked/>$currentCat checked";
```

Notice that you have

```
checked="checked"
```

Removing the ="checked" portion will fix the problem.